# How to efficiently distinguish the rewired edges in WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random, data, cluster-analysis

The [`WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution.html) function is a way to construct random graphs based on [Watts and Strogatz small world model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts_and_Strogatz_model). The `WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution` is constructed starting from [`CirculantGraph[n,Range[k]]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQp7n.png) (`k=2` unless you assign another value for it)and rewiring each edge with probability **p**. Each edge is rewired by changing one of the vertices, making sure that no loop or multiple edge is created. For instance,

```
WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[100,0.05]
```

can give:
[image: Random Graph]

I need to distinguish the rewired(short-cut) edges from the original ones so I can measure some of their statistical properties(Average of short-cut and non-short-cut edge betweenness). One possibility was to forget about this subroutine in *Mathematica*, and construct everything I need from scratch. I have not ruled out that possibility yet, but since I will be dealing with not so tiny graphs(about 500 nodes) and I will have to repeat the procedure few hundred times in order to obtain reliable average values; I would rather do something more efficient.

Another idea which I had was to calculate the [`EdgeBetweennessCentrality`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeBetweennessCentrality.html) of all the edges and then cluster them into two groups(one naively expects the betweenness of the short-cut edges to be higher). Unfortunately this doesn't work because the edges close to rewired edge will also get higher betweenness centrality and I couldn't distinguish them apart from the each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the brute force way:

```
og = CirculantGraph[100, Range[2]];

g = RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[100, 0.05]];

oelist = Sort /@ EdgeList[og];

elist = Sort /@ EdgeList[g];

rewired = Complement[oelist, elist]
```

> {4 <-> 6, 19 <-> 20, 21 <-> 23, 26 <-> 27, 31 <-> 32, 33 <-> 35,   44
>   <-> 45, 55 <-> 56, 56 <-> 58, 59 <-> 61, 70 <-> 72}

Comment: Although it's brute force, I like this answer. Also, I didn't know `WattsStrogatz` literally uses `circulantgraph`!! Thanks.